# Sisters dog has a fungal infection on the belly

Tags: dogs, health

Is a fungal infection on my sisters west highland white contagious to my dog who is a Lhasa 13 years old but very healthy 
My dog is a male

Comment: is the type of fungi known,many types of fungi is a natural part of the skin and only gives problems if a dog is treated with antibiotics or steroids.